# Child image not allowing top layer change onmouseover

Tags: javascript, css, layer, onmouseover

Running into a problem that seems to ONLY be an issue with IE, and I'm not sure how to fix it.  I know a lot of people do this but I'm not sure how to make it properly work with IE.

I'm working on an ecommerce site where we want some details of a product to overlay over the top of the product image when hovering over the image.  The containing DIV is the javascript trigger, but if your mouse hits the image before it hits the div, the div class change doesn't execute.

http://jsfiddle.net/eQMzg/

If you go to the jsfiddle, if you start the hover from the right or left side of the div, it works perfectly.  If you start it from the bottom or top, where the image is expanded to, it doesn't.

```
<div class="product">
                    <div class="product_activitylayer" align="right" onmouseout="this.className='';this.className='product_activitylayer'" onmouseover="this.className='';this.className='product_activitylayer_hover'">
            </div>

        <div class="product_containertop" align="center"> 
            <img src="images/demoimages/product.jpg" height="160"> 
        </div>
      </div>

.product {
width:244px;
height:221px;
display:block;
float:left;
margin:0px 3px 5px 0px;
border-top:solid;
border-top-color:#10B0E5;
border-top-width:6px;
}
.product_containertop {
height:160px;
width:244px;
background:#FFFFFF;
border-bottom:solid;
border-bottom-width:1px;
border-bottom-color:#C7EEFA;
margin-bottom:2px;
}

.product_activitylayer {
height:160px;
width:244px;
position:absolute;
z-index:999;

}
.product_activitylayer_hover {
height:160px;
width:244px;
position:absolute;
z-index:999;
background:#00CCFF;
opacity:.5;
filter:alpha(opacity="50");


}
```

Comment: UPDATE: opacity in the layer cannot be taken to 0, I have objects in the layer that need to be viewed (I just initially removed them for the sake of ease of explanation thinking these objects would be irrelevant to the solution.  here's the updated jsfiddle...jsfiddle.net/NETJ4/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John,

This one is a known bug in IE. If any element has transparent background - IE does not takes executes the hover on it. You can fix it by applying the background to .product_activitylayer and set it's opacity to 0

See I updated your fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/NETJ4/1/

```
.product_activitylayer {
    height:160px;
    width:244px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
    background:#00CCFF;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity="0");
}
```

Or here is a improved version using jQuery
http://jsfiddle.net/zzLr6/2/

Comment: Hi @shekhardesigner , thanks for the response!  What you did works (actually, except the jQuery one, which doesn't seem to be functioning) but the requirement of setting the opacity to zero is something I'm going to have to get around because I have objects inside of the activitylayer that need to be viewed.  I removed them for the sake of ease.  Take a look as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/NETJ4/2

Comment: ...continued @shekharddesigner , so I initially thought if I just post a layer for triggering and one that sits on top of that trigger layer to hold these various icons, we'd be good, but putting a layer on top of the triggering layer makes it unable to trigger as well, so I'm back to square one.  Any thoughts?  The key issue with IE is that you HAVE to set the background color for it to think there's an actual layer there.  Then, as you did, you have to take the opacity to 0, which gives me fits since I have objects in the layer.

Comment: Use spacer.gif (transparent image of a pixel as background and change the it on hover :) )